# How can I reduce the window in xcode to 50%?

Tags: xcode

[image]I usually code while watching videos on YouTube. However, it is difficult to see the screen because the magnification of the xcode window is not reduced as shown in the picture. The spectacle app does not apply either. please give me a solution :)

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mac-help/mchl4fbe2921/mac

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the new Mac features, but I can't use it with the Chrome browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tile your windows on mac by hover over the green button in the top-left of the window. you may need to press & hold the option key in some cases.

or u can use [rectangle](https://rectangleapp.com/)

Comment: I just found a solution. I can change the window size in xcode to 50% of screen by doing view>hidetoolbar. Thank you so much for your kind reply